# Multiselect using comma separated selectedOption string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following:

```
<select id="some-id"  multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: $root.Titles,
      optionsText: 'FullName',
      optionsValue: 'ID',
      selectedOptions:TITLESID>
</select>
```

the above TITLESID come as a comma separated string, I would like to change that to an array before it gets here or it won't work.

I know something like `.split()` in javascript should do the trick but any advice is going to be appreciated.

Here is my model:

```
     var TIds = "2,3,4";
     var TITLESID= ko.observableArray(TIds.split(","));
     var myMainmodel = new TypeOfModel(thismodel, animal, TITLESID);
```

Comment: Please update your question and include your view model logic: make sure the question contains a [repro](http://sscce.org) for us to work with. In addition it would help if you tell us what you tried (e.g. what you did with `split()`, etc) and be specific about the problem

Comment: `Split()` is indeed intended to do exactly what you would like to do. However, I would stick with the CSV notation and only splt this in your custom binding, as the CSV notation is the one used to post multiple select values to the server...

Comment: @Jeroen I tried above updated question and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than string.split(), I don't think there's anything that will really be able to help.

```
viewmodel.TITLESID = viewmodel.TITLESID.split(',');
```

You'll want to do that before applying bindings if the TITLESID property isn't an observable. If it is an observable, you'll want to do this instead:

```
viewmodel.TITLESID(viewmodel.TITLESID().split(','));
```

...to ensure the view gets updated when the value changes.

Comment: I updated my question, that did not work as I need an array of those split numbers.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure you're not getting an array?  String.split() returns an array.  Maybe the issue is that the array is an array of strings and not numbers?  Try this:

`var TITLESID = ko.observableArray();`

`var tmp = TIds.split(",");`

`ko.utils.arrayForEach(tmp, function(str){ TITLESID.push(parseInt(str,10));});`

`console.log(TITLESID());`

Then open your dev console in Chrome and see what's been output.

Comment: In case you were wondering, it worked after I parsed the 1-3 to int.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it!